# how to divide a variable by a digit?

Tags: tkinter, divide

so ive been trying to make a cps counter, im now working on the timer and this is my code

```py
from tkinter import *
import random
from tkinter import Button
from itertools import cycle
import time

number = 0
root = Tk()
root.title("Programme")
root.geometry('1920x1080')
root["bg"]="black"
label = "your corrent cps is {}"

def clicked():
    global number
    number += 1
    button.config(text=number)

my_label = Label(root,height = 2,width = 10, text = "", bg = "white")
my_label.pack(pady=20)

def cps():
    (number / 10)
    print(cps)

my_label.after(10000, cps)

    # enter code here

button = Button(root, height = 20,
                width = 200,
                text=format(number),
                command=clicked,)
button.pack(side=TOP, padx=15, pady=250)

root.mainloop()
```

the main problem is here

```py
def cps():
    (number / 10)
    print(cps)
```

instead of printing out a number it prints this

```
<function cps at 0x0000018186E71A60>
```

anyone know what i can do?

Comment: I think you mean `def cps(): print(number / 10)`, or `def cps: return number / 10`.

Answer (score 0):

You are printing the function, i believe you want to print the number/10. So just replace the print(cps) with print(number/10). Than it sould run just fine.